# For-Next Loop Visual Basic

Tags: vba, for-loop

I'm trying to create a program that adds all of the numbers in between two user-inputted numbers. However, my program appears to be printing 1 number below, and I cant figure it out at all. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    Dim minNum As Integer
    Dim maxNum As Integer
    Dim runningCount As Integer
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim Cont As Integer

    minNum = InputBox("please input the lower number, between 1 and 100")
    maxNum = InputBox("Please input the higer number, between 1 and 100")

    For Cont = minNum To (maxNum - 1)
        runningCount = runningCount + 1
        total = total + (minNum + runningCount)
    Next Cont
    MsgBox(total)
```

Comment: Do you want to print a sum of numbers between min and max or you want to print every number and a sum?

Comment: You don't need to use `runningCount`, you already have `Cont` variable. You can just do this: `total = total + Cont` in a loop in order to calculate the sum.

Comment: yeah i was looking to print the sum. thanks for the help! got it working with "total = total + Cont"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you trying to do. But in order to understand what's the meaning of the resulting number you can use a string variable which will hold all internal calculations. I created a variable `totalLog` for this:

```
Dim minNum As Integer
Dim maxNum As Integer
Dim runningCount As Integer
Dim total As Integer
Dim Cont As Integer

Dim totalLog As String

minNum = InputBox("please input the lower number, between 1 and 100")
maxNum = InputBox("Please input the higer number, between 1 and 100")

For Cont = minNum To (maxNum - 1)
    runningCount = runningCount + 1
    total = total + (minNum + runningCount)
    totalLog = totalLog & "+" & (minNum + runningCount)
Next Cont
MsgBox (total)

totalLog = totalLog & "=" & total
MsgBox (Right(totalLog, Len(totalLog) - 1))
```

Now if, for example, you pick numbers 10 and 15 as your lower and higher numbers you will see a log string "11+12+13+14+15=65". So the lower number isn't included in this total, but the higher number is included. Maybe that's the reason of your confusion.

As a small suggestion, I wouldn't use extra `runningCount` variable here since you already have `Cont` counter. Here's how you can change you program in order to add all numbers between starting & ending number **including** this numbers:

```
Dim minNum As Integer
Dim maxNum As Integer
Dim total As Integer
Dim Cont As Integer

minNum = InputBox("please input the lower number, between 1 and 100")
maxNum = InputBox("Please input the higer number, between 1 and 100")

For Cont = minNum To maxNum
    total = total + Cont
Next Cont
MsgBox (total)
```

Looks easier for me.